# How to hide slide menu programmatically without animation in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In `logout` function I need to hide side menu and navigate to a new state. To hide menu I'm using `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft` and it works well:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  $state.go('login');
});
```

The problem is that the both actions are performed with animation and it doesn't look good. So I want to hide side menu without animation. Is it possible in Ionic (I'm using Ionic v1.x)?